# Bot Composer: Access Webex AttachementAction

Tags: botframework

I am trying to build a Webex bot with the Microsoft Bot Composer. When using adaptive cards, the data (turn.activity.value) is formatted to a dictionary:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WipxL.png

How can I access these data?

The "code-first" bot is doing the following:
https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/62.webex-adapter/Bots/EchoBot.cs#L49

Is this also possible with the composer?

Comment: Does `turn.activity.value.<KEY>` work? From your example, it would be `turn.activity.value.a____` (can't tell what the key is as it was masked).

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work like that.

Comment: Can you use Composer's built in webchat or emulator and show what the activity JSON looks like? You can also use Composer's watch tab to run/check certain properties and values.